I get the error "_RenderInkFeatures object was given an infinite size during layout." in Flutter
I am trying to implement slider functionality in my code. Although I predefined a max value for the slider, it still says that the slider has an infinite value
I have given the code below:

The error:

I would appreciate it if someone can tell me what is wrong in my code..
Thanks!

Wrap the Slider in a SizedBox like
const SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
  child: Slider(...),
)

